# Is Enumerator a variant of Turing machine that starts with empty string and builds according to the description of language

Tags: turing-machines, recursively-enumerable

My understanding is an "Enumerator" is a Turing Machine that: instead of taking an input string, then going through a series of transitions and "halting" or "not halting" on it, it does not accept any input string and it starts with a blank string and builds the final string according to the rules of the language

For example: if our language was L = { w | w is made up of 0^n1^n, where n >= 0 }

A normal Turing Machine would have a input tape and it would receive an input on that tape and this normal Turing Machine would go through a series of transitions to deduce whether this string belongs to the language or not

An enumerator, a variant of normal Turing Machine, would have 3 different tapes, an input tape + work tape + output tape. Since, we don't have any input we don't interact with input tape at all ( which means we can remove that tape if we want to ), the work tape is used as a temporary workspace for constructing strings - at the end when we finish constructing a string we may choose to copy the symbols from the work tape to output tape and adding a "#" symbol on the output tape at the end of the output tape which will act as a separator from the next string and we will then blank out the work tape, the output tape acts like a printer for string with '#' separating different strings

In an enumerator, to produce strings for the given language, we will start on a start state and then take the transition to write 'n' number of '0' on the work tape, then writing 'n' number of '1' on worktape ( using appropriate logic of crossing out / blank symbol for 'counting' ). Then once we are done with that we will go to a special state called the "enumeratored state" which will copy the symbols from the work tape to output tape ( again through a series of transitions ) and then blank out the work tape + add the separator symbol on the output tape

This will continue on forever for strings of all lengths unless we have designed to produce specific strings of this language

In a nutshell, enumerator just helps building strings according to a pattern whilst turing machines help to check if a certain strings adheres to a certain pattern

Which also gives rise to the theorem that: "A language is accepted by a Turing machine if and only if some enumerator enumerates it"

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I suggest you read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) for some insight.

Comment: @Nathaniel Just confirming, but after reading the wikipedia page - whatever i said in this post is correct, Am i right?

Comment: @PratikHadawale What you said in the post are pretty good understanding. I would say they are correct if you rephrase them in formal terms.

Comment: The usage of "pattern" in the question might be misleading. The only "pattern" of a recursively-enumerable language (or "the description of language") is the algorithm (a.k.a a Turing machine) that produces/accepts the language (or an equivalent algorithm) in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of "an enumerator" is pretty good.

In fact, you have recovered the origin of the term "recursively enumerable" as explained in the textbook *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser.

> **ENUMERATORS**
>
> As we mentioned earlier, some people use the term recursively enumerable language for Turing-recognizable language. That term originates from a type of
> Turing machine variant called an enumerator. Loosely defined, an enumerator
> is a Turing machine with an attached printer. The Turing machine can use
> that printer as an output device to print strings. Every time the Turing machine wants to add a string to the list, it sends the string to the printer. Exercise 3.4 asks you to give a formal definition of an enumerator. The following figure depicts aschematic of this model.
> [image: Schematic of an enumerator by Michael Spiser]

Your theorem also appears in that book.

> THEOREM **3.21**
>
> A language is Turing-recognizable if and only if some enumerator enumerates it.